# Unable to call function. (Not an error)

Tags: python, python-2.7

```
#!/usr/bin/python
# -*- coding: u8 -*-
import csv

def csvreader():
    f = open('tb.csv', "rU")
    reader = csv.reader(f)
    rownum = 0
    for row in reader:
        if rownum == 0:
            header = row
        else:
            colnum = 0
                for col in row:
                print '%-9s : %s' % (header[colnum], col) 
                colnum += 1
        print""
        rownum += 1
    f.close()

print "Welcome to the Libary of Alexandria"
print ""
print "Please select an option by entering the corresponding number from the         following:"
print ""
print "① : Search Database"
print "② : Add Data"
print "⚕ : Πληροφορίες συστήματος"
print ""
selection = (raw_input("Please enter a number:\n"))
while True:
    try:
        selection = int(selection)
        break
    except ValueError:
        selection = (raw_input('\033[31mERROR: Please enter a single digit corresponding to a selection.\033[0m\n'))
if selection == '1':
    search = csvreader()
    print search
```

Hi,
The function csvreader works fine on its own, however when i attempt to call it by putting the funtion by itself, or doing assigning it to a variable and printing it, it prints nothing. The screen outputs

```
Welcome to the Libary of Alexandria

Please select an option by entering the corresponding number from the following:

① : Search Database
② : Add Data
⚕ : Πληροφορίες συστήματος

Please enter a number:
1
```

And then nothing.

Im using netbeans on python 2.7.5.

Any help with this or the rest of my code would be appreciated.

Comment: shouldn't it be `if selection == 1`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should change the if condition to

```
if selection == 1:
```

`selection` being an int should be compared with an int value.

Also the function `csvreader()` should return something.

Comment: Thank you, I thought it should however, selection being compared with a string was the issue.

Answer (score 1):

You function is not called because you are comparing an integer with a string.
Replace your

```
if selection == '1':
```

with

```
if selection == 1:
```